# Creating a tree using recursion

Tags: list, recursion, tree, functional-programming, ocaml

I am trying to create a tree from an int list in OCAML. I am very new to functional programming. This is my function so far:

```
let rec theList (lst : int list) = 
 match lst with 
  | [] -> Empty
  | h::t -> insert Empty h::theList List.tl lst
```

when insert is a function that creates a node and puts the value of h in the node. I try to traverse through the list but at the colons after I call insert with the arguments I get the error: "Error: The variant type bstTree has no constructor ::" as this a type I defined as:

```
type bstTree = Empty | bstTree * Node of int * bstTree
```

In a broad sense all I am trying to do is recurse through the list and call insert on each int in the list. I have been working on this for awhile now so any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are many problems with your code (to be expected if you're just starting out).

First, your type definition is not syntactically valid:

```
# type bstTree = Empty | bstTree * Node of int * bstTree;;
Error: Syntax error
```

Most likely you want something more like this:

```
type bstTree = Empty | Node of bstTree * int * bstTree
```

Second, you're defining a function named `theList`, but inside the function you call a function named `fromList`. I have a suspicion that these are supposed to be the same name.

Third, there is no need to call `List.tl` since you have already matched the tail of the list under the name `t`.

Fourth, you are going to need more parentheses in your expression. A good starting point might be something like this:

```
insert Empty h (fromList List.tl lst)
```

As the compiler is pointing out, you can't apply the constructor `::` to values of type `bstTree`. The `::` constructor only works for building a list from an element and another (smaller) list.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I made the necessary changes you proposed and on the line: 
`h::t -> insert Empty h (fromList List.tl lst)` 
 I am now getting an error saying : "Error: This function has type bstTree -> int -> bstTree
       It is applied to too many arguments; maybe you forgot a `;'.
insert: bstTree → int → bstTree"

And I don't really see/understand the issue. @Jeffrey